# Why Textarea.Innertext gives me null point exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, textarea, nullreferenceexception

```
<textarea id="TextAreaSend" runat="server" name="SendText">
```

I created text area to write something.And will save it to database with linq to entity.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextAreaSend.InnerText))
        {

            int ticketno = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TicketNo"]);
            var source = from tickettext in entities.Tickets
                         where tickettext.TicketNo == ticketno
                         select tickettext;
            Ticket ticket = source.Single();
//This is where null point exception is
            ticket.Answer.AnswerText = TextAreaSend.InnerText;

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
```

ticket.Answer.AnswerText = TextAreaSend.InnerText; In this line i
receive;

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Why is that? How can i fix it?

Comment: What is `ticket.Answer`? Are you sure that is not what is giving you the null reference?

Comment: It is a class created by entity Ticket.It is a table in my database with navigation property i am just pointing where to write.

Comment: But i will check something

Comment: `ticket.Answer` is likely the item that's `null`. If it's not failing on the first line of that code when it does the null or empty check on `TextAreaSend.InnerText`, then it can't be failing when reading it for the assignment to `AnswerText`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not failing on the first line of that code when it does the null or empty check on `TextAreaSend.InnerText`, then it can't be failing for the same reason when reading the property value for the assignment to `AnswerText`.

`ticket` cannot be `null` here either because you would receive a different exception if 0 or more than 1 `Ticket` was returned by the query.

What we have left is that `ticket.Answer` is likely the item that's `null` here, not `ticket` or `TextAreaSend`. You are attempting to write to a property on an object that is `null`.

Comment: I should have added ticketno into database.It just couldnt find the ticketno and answerText so cant find anything..Sorry my mistake i was a little rushed to do this

Answer (score 1):

I would check into how many entities are being returned when you call "source.Single()".  There can be exceptions thrown if there is more than one entity being returned or no entities being returned when using "Single()".  Additionally, if you use "SingleOrDefault()", you can do a check for null prior to moving on with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks i will use it when i test also..